# Bundle Resources Access Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, bundle

I am creating a swift framework for reuse my code in other app.

For reuse xib files I created a Bundle Resources in the framework across:

```
.xcodeproj -> target -> + -> Os X -> Framework & Library -> Bundle
```

and I added to my new bundle the xib files, but now I am not able to acces to this bundle in the main app, I try with:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier:"PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER")
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: SomClassInABundle.self)